# Parse String to Date and calculate diference between on Two dates

Tags: android, string, date

Well, Im working on Android and I got a date in String format from JSon with format : "dd-MM-yyyy", and date today from system, so I cant to get the diference between two dates. I did it.

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",java.util.Locale.getDefault());
String fechaActual = df1.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println("=========> Date Today => "+fechaActual); 

fechaEvaluacion = json_data.getString("fechaEvaluacion");
Date fechaEvDate = Date.valueOf(fechaEvaluacion);
long fechaInicial = fechaEvDate.getTime();
long fechaFinal = xDate.getTime(); 
long diferencia =  ( fechaFinal- fechaInicial ); 
final long days = diferencia / 24;
System.out.println("The difference between the two days is: "+days);
if(days < 3){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(200);
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tienes "+tipoEvaluacion+" de: "+nombreAsignatura+" en "+days+", el día:  "+fechaEvaluacion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast2.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
            toast2.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Finally in variable "days" I got some numbres like -13140000000 or 13176000000

I want some help with this,I tried alot of thing for parse date with no results.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide like this

```
final long days = diferencia / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```